# Order by y-Value in Facet Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following data.frame

```
RANK_GROUP <- as.factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
CHANNEL_CATEGORY <- as.factor(c(1,  2,  10, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 43, 44, 1,  2,  10, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 43))
CATEGORY_COUNT <- c(105, 23, 417, 10, 58, 6, 535, 211, 215, 465, 28, 273, 70, 47, 7,1,21,3,69, 14, 493, 3, 44, 3, 516, 162, 253, 516, 24, 228, 64, 59, 2, 45)

data <- data.frame(RANK_GROUP, CHANNEL_CATEGORY,CATEGORY_COUNT)
```

I want to make a Facet-Plot with a barplot for each distribution:

```
ggplot(data = data) +
  aes(x=CHANNEL_CATEGORY, y = CATEGORY_COUNT) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position ="dodge", colour="black") +
  facet_grid(. ~ RANK_GROUP)
```

[image: Plot]

How can I order the plots according to their y-value withing each facet-plot?

Answer (score 1):

took the help of cookbook,

```
library(dplyr)

pd <- data %>%
      group_by(RANK_GROUP) %>%
      top_n(nrow(data), abs(CATEGORY_COUNT)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(RANK_GROUP, CATEGORY_COUNT) %>%
      mutate(order = row_number())

 pd$order <- as.factor(pd$order)

ggplot(data = pd) +
  aes(x=order, y = CATEGORY_COUNT) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position ="dodge", colour="black") +
  facet_grid(. ~ RANK_GROUP)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = CHANNEL_CATEGORY , breaks = order)+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = .5, size = 8)) +
 labs(x="Channel")
```

[image]

Comment: this does not reorder within each facet. As you see, the first facet does not have increasing y-values

Comment: this looks sorted, but what happened to the x-axis?

Comment: that makes it discrete, but i want to have the Categories on the x-axis

Comment: +  labs(x = "Channel") : to change the x-axis label.

Comment: Compare the values for CHANNEL_CATEGORY in pd with the chart.